# Radiobutton text in-line

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I'm trying to get a Yes/No RadioButtonList set up on my page rendered as follows:

> [=] Yes [=] No

Currently, my code in my .skin file looks like this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The RBL is rendering like this:

> [=] [=]
>      Yes  No

I haven't written any CSS for it so that's all that's involved in the list's presentation.

To make it clear, I want to get the Yes/No text next to their respective radio buttons. Can anyone explain to me why they aren't and how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't face this issue all of sudden. But I mentioned some small amount of Width(50px) to RadioButtonList then it was reproduced. Simply increase the Width of RadioButtonList by some amount. it will be rendered as you want.

In my case I gave `Width="95px"` as follows

```
    <asp:RadioButtonList Width="95px" ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Output

[image]

Comment: turns out there was css being applied in my code that was wrecking it, but this is still a very valid possibility. It didn't solve my problem obviously, but I give it a +1 anyway

Comment: I think it's surely css width issue. Something might have overwriting width css. Try by applying inline css for width with !important. Like style=" width:100px !important".